# MapServer SOS (Sensor Observation Service) Configuration

Tags: gis, mapserver, ogc, umn-mapserver

I tried to set up MapServer SOS but I faced a problem: the SOS doesn't return anything. You may see the map file I have created below:

```
MAP  
  NAME "SOS_DEMO"   
  STATUS ON   
  SIZE 400 300   
  EXTENT -180 -90 180 90   
  UNITS METERS   
  SHAPEPATH "C:\ms4w\apps\tutorial\data"   
  IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255   

  WEB   
    IMAGEPATH "C:\ms4w\apps\tutorial\templates"   
    IMAGEURL "C:\ms4w\apps\tutorial\images"   
    METADATA   
      "sos_onlineresource" "http://127.0.0.1:8282/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c:/ms4w/mysos.map?"   
      "sos_title"          "My SOS Demo Server"   
      "sos_srs"            "EPSG:4326"   
      "sos_enable_request" "*"   
    END   
  END   

  PROJECTION   
    "init=epsg:4326"   
  END   

  LAYER   
    NAME "sos_point"   
    METADATA   
      "sos_procedure"  "ifgi-sensor-1"   
      "sos_offering_id" "WQ1289"   
      "sos_observedproperty_id" "Water Quality"   
      "sos_describesensor_url" "http://127.0.0.1:8181/DescribeSensor.xml"   
    END   

    TYPE POINT   
    STATUS ON   
    DATA 'sospoint'   
    PROJECTION   
      "init=epsg:4326"   
    END   
    CLASS   
      NAME 'sospoint'   
      STYLE   
        COLOR 255 128 128   
      END   
    END   
  END    
END
```

As you see, I tried to retrieve sensor data from a shapefile. The message returned by the SOS is:

```
<om:ObservationCollection xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:swe="http://www.opengis.net/swe/1.0.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sos="http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0" xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" xmlns:om="http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0" gml:id="WQ1289" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/om/1.0.0/om.xsd http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver http://127.0.0.1:8282/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c:/ms4w/mysos.map?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=urban">  
<om:member>
<om:Observation>
<om:procedure xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:procedure:ifgi-sensor-1"/>
<om:observedProperty>
<swe:CompositePhenomenon gml:id="Water Quality" dimension="3">
<swe:component xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC-SWE:1:Id"/>
<swe:component xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC-SWE:1:sensor_nam"/>
<swe:component xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC-SWE:1:sensor_val"/>
</swe:CompositePhenomenon>
</om:observedProperty>
<om:resultDefinition>
<swe:DataBlockDefinition>
<swe:components>
<swe:DataRecord/>
</swe:components>
<swe:encoding>
<swe:TextBlock tokenSeparator="," blockSeparator=" " decimalSeparator="."/>
</swe:encoding>
</swe:DataBlockDefinition>
</om:resultDefinition>
<om:result></om:result>
</om:Observation>
</om:member>
</om:ObservationCollection>
```

Although I put 6 observations into the shapefile but the SOS doesn't return any. Would you please let me know what I should do to resolve the problem?!

Thanks, 
Ebrahim

Comment: what request did you use?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps better ask here? https://gis.stackexchange.com/